# Error: Cannot find module "angularfire2/database-deprecated" appmodule ionic 3, Angularfire2

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3, angularfire2

I am try to connect to database in firebase. Here is the app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';

import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireDatabaseModule } from 'angularfire2/database';

import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  providers: [
    AngularFireDatabase,
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

The error is in this line

```
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireDatabaseModule } from 'angularfire2/database';
```

I have tried this also
    import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireDatabaseModule } from 'angularfire2/***database-deprecated***';

But the the error just change.

> Runtime Error Cannot find module "angularfire2/database" Stack Error:
>   Cannot find module "angularfire2/database"
>       at Object.217 (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:78:7)
>       at **webpack_require** (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:55:30)
>       at Object.194 (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:60:70)
>       at **webpack_require** (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:55:30)
>       at webpackJsonpCallback (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:26:23)
>       at http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:1:1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start)

in terminal: `npm install firebase --save`

In your app.module.ts create firebase config object:

```
// Set the configuration for your app
// TODO: Replace with your project's config object
var config = {
  apiKey: "apiKey",
  authDomain: "projectId.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://databaseName.firebaseio.com",
  storageBucket: "bucket.appspot.com"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

// Get a reference to the database service
var database = firebase.database();
```

**After the call on Page .ts:**

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
```

Comment: I am actually a learner. So it would be good kindly describe me, why we need to add import * as firebase from 'firebase';

Comment: To Read and Write Data, See this https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once

Comment: yes.. I got it what you saying.. But in ionic we use angularfire2 v5 to connect firebase. So is it good to use.

Comment: Use it example https://www.joshmorony.com/building-a-crud-ionic-2-application-with-firebase-angularfire/

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with `"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.10"`
The solution for me was uninstall `angularfire2^5.0.0-rc.10` and `install angularfire2^5.0.0-rc.9`

```
npm uninstall angularfire2
npm install angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.9
```

I confirm this works, solution by @jsariasgeek

[Issue discussion](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/1688)